# Scala class to implement two Java Interfaces - how?

Tags: java, scala, interface

I have just started learning Scala and I'm now wondering how I could implement two different Java interfaces with one Scala class? Let's say I have the following interfaces written in Java

```
public interface EventRecorder {
    public void abstract record(Event event); 
}

public interface TransactionCapable {
    public void abstract commit();
}
```

But a Scala class can extend only one class at a time. How can I have a Scala class that could fulfill both contracts? Do I have to map those interfaces into traits?

Note, my Scala classes would be used from Java as I am trying to inject new functionality written in Scala into an existing Java application. And the existing framework expects that both interface contracts are fulfilled.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The second interface can be implemented with the `with` keyword

```
class ImplementingClass extends EventRecorder with TransactionCapable {
  def record(event: Event) {}
  def commit() {}
}
```

Further on each subsequent interface is separated with the keyword `with`.

```
class Clazz extends InterfaceA
  with InterfaceB
  with InterfaceC {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried it but IntelliJ spewed out some vague syntax error. I have to try it again and see if the project was setup incorrectly.

Comment: Should it be mentioned, that subsequent interfaces are separated with the keyword `with`? Eg. `x extends y with z with q`.