# How do I make a Scala class Hadoop Writable?

Tags: scala, serialization, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a Scala class:

```
class Features (
  val count: Int = 1,
  val firstTime: Long = Long.MaxValue,
  val lastTime: Long = Long.MinValue)
```

which is held in a Spark pair RDD with String as the key:

```
val features: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, features.Features)]
```

and I would like to save the contents with something like:

```
features.saveAsSequenceFile(path)
```

However the Features class does not implement org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable and I don't know how to implement this.  Without it, the error I get is:

```
No implicit view available from features.Features => org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable.
```

How do I make Features Hadoop Writable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement `Writable` interface in your classes. There are two general ways:

1. Implement writable in you case class
2. Implement type class and provide implicit conversion to it

Comment: Ah.  The problem I had was not knowing how to implement an interface in Scala.  Here's a link that helped me: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068540/scala-class-to-implement-two-java-interfaces-how]